# Is it possible? $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{a}{b}$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = 0$

Let $a$ and $b$  are positive integers numbers.

> Is it possible?
>   $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{a}{b}$$

Comment: Yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: For To solve an issue, I asked.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = \frac{a}{x}$. You can guess $g(x)$ for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely**.

Take for $a,b\ne 0$:

$$f(x)=\frac ax$$

and $$g(x)=\frac bx.$$

Then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac ab$$

but $$\lim_{x\to\infty } f(x)=0$$

and same for $g$.

---

More generally (since you asked in the comments), take any $\phi$ (and $\phi(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$) such that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \phi(x)=+\infty.$$

Then $f(x)=a/\phi(x)$ and $g(x)=b/\phi(x)$ give you another example.

Comment: You might want to switch $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you very much.+1.Please explain me,Can there be other examples?

Comment: @Newuser Yes, I edited my answer to answer your additional question.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Joseph.It helped me a lot.Although the question was rejected. I did not exactly ask the question. Because, latex knowledge is very small. As a result, I wrote in general. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $f$ satisfying your requirement and $g(x) = \frac{b \, f(x)}{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples. You can also define $f(x)=\sin(ax)$ and $g(x)=\sin(bx)$. It is also possible to choose $f$ and $g$ different, i.e. $f(x)=2(e^{\sqrt{a}x}-1-\sqrt{a}x)$ and $g(x)=\ln^2(1+\sqrt{b}x)$. The trick is to choose $f$ and $g$ which goes at the same speed to $0$ and then add your constants $a$ and $b$.